# Foursquare API : Retrieve principal Venue Photo

Tags: foursquare

I'm using search Foursquare API to get list of venues but in result I don't have principal picture of venue (like profile picture in a facebook page).

Is there a way to retrieve it, using an other API ?

This API give me all photos and I can't retrieve only profile picture (https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos)

I want for example url of photo with logo Mcdonald here : https://fr.foursquare.com/v/mcdonalds/4b24227df964a520ea6124e3

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint? There is a boolean parameter `venuePhotos=1` that will include the venue profile photo in the response.

Comment: this is not valid anymore.